# Is there any Multi-Language Word Translator app or tool to learn multiple langueage at the same time?

Tags: resource-request, vocabulary, multiple-languages

I am looking a source that I can learn or look a word in multiple language.

*For example:* lets say, I want to learn `English` - `Russian` - `Turkish` at the same time.
The app:

```
a       - один        - bir
abandon - покидать    - terk etmek
ability - способность - kabiliyet
...
...
```

Comment: You could take a look at Google Sheets. There is a formula called GOOGLETRANSLATE() that lets you accomplish what you're describing here.

Comment: Yes it is easy to do. Thank you

Comment: Your approach would go very much against my intuition. In my experience, learning a language is best done in a setting where no other language gets in the way (including your native tongue). As concepts behind words never match 100% between two languages, classic two-language dictionaries are already flawed. Of course, this gets worse with three languages, and unnaturally stresses your brain to keep three different language systems active at the same time. Learn how to express your thoughts in a new language, not how to translate words between languages.